# Define attribute and value for standard key-value pair in JSON using JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode

Tags: c#, .net, json, xml, json.net

I understand this is working as intended but I am trying to simplify and reduce my output from the `SerializeXmlNode`.

Code:

```
XmlDocument XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
XMLDoc.LoadXml(NewXML);

string EventDataJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(XMLDoc, 0, true);
```

Here is my XML:

```
<DataEntries>
    <Data Name="Direction">in</Data> 
    <Data Name="SourceAddress">222.0.0.252</Data> 
    <Data Name="SourcePort">5355</Data> 
    <Data Name="DestAddress">192.168.1.24</Data> 
</DataEntries>
```

Current JSON output:

```
{"@Name":"Direction","#text":"in"},
{"@Name":"SourceAddress","#text":"222.0.0.252"},
{"@Name":"SourcePort","#text":"5355"},
{"@Name":"DestAddress","#text":"192.168.1.24"}
```

Desired JSON output (indention is irrelevant):

```
{
    "Direction":"in",
    "SourceAddress":"222.0.0.252",
    "SourcePort":"5355",
    "DestAddress":"192.168.1.24"
}
```

I'd prefer not to use regular expression if I don't have to but really I'm open to anything at this point. My other option is to use `JavaScriptSerializer` but if there is a way to do this within JSON.net library, that would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [Converting between JSON and XML](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm), *If the XML created from JSON doesn't match what you want, then you will need to convert it manually.*  In this case, since you are loading your XML into an `XmlDocument` beforehand, it seems easiest to pre-process the XML like so:

```
XmlDocument XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
XMLDoc.LoadXml(NewXML);

foreach (XmlElement entry in XMLDoc.SelectNodes("//DataEntries"))
{
    var data = entry.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().ToList();
    foreach (var d in data)
    {
        var e = XMLDoc.CreateElement(d.Attributes["Name"].Value);
        e.InnerText = d.InnerText;
        entry.AppendChild(e);
    }
    foreach (var d in data)
    {
        entry.RemoveChild(d);
    }
}

string EventDataJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(XMLDoc, 0, true);
```

You might consider switching to the more modern [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) API.  If so, your code would look like:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(NewXML);
foreach (var entry in doc.Descendants("DataEntries"))
{
    var data = entry.Elements("Data").ToList();
    foreach (var d in data)
    {
        entry.Add(new XElement((string)d.Attribute("Name"), d.Value));
    }
    data.Remove();
}

string EventDataJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(doc, 0, true);
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QK5gHF).